# any way to have image change upon hover while also acting as link?

Tags: html, css

I tried this...

```
.home {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-image: url("---");
}
.home:hover {
background-image: url("xxx");
}
</style>

<a href="link"><div class="home"></a>
```

... The image changes upon hover, but the link doesn't work when clicked.

Comment: You could update the link (href attribute) of the HTML anchor element with Javascript on a hover/mouse event. Did you already try to use Javascript to do so?

Comment: Hi, what's `href="link"` expected to do?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can change `background-image` on `:hover`.

```css
.bg_link {
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  background: url(https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/000000) center/cover;
}

.bg_link:hover {
  background: url(https://dummyimage.com/600x400/d145d1/d145d1) center/cover;
}
```

```html
<a class="bg_link" href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">
  
</a>
```